# Manipulating input .txt with wildcard

Tags: c, file, unix, io, wildcard

I have a question about manipulating wildcards when these are text entries. 
For example:

1. have the following command line, where can I get two texts as input. Texts of the directory itself or passes the path of the texts

   ```
   prog -a text.txt text2.txt
   ```
2. another option for the command 1 is using wildcard, which is carried out a search in the root directory or spending the directory path

   ```
   prog - the text * .txt
   ```

I wanted to know if there is any GNU library function that can return me these files or directory of these files when using wildcard as in option 2.

Comment: The wild card will get expanded by the shell - your program won't see it.

Comment: I needed to write a program in C type the 'GNU grep', and read the text input. I used the glob () method to it, as indicated by '@Sleafar' and worked well. Example: http://delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_426.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call your program from a shell like `bash` the wildcards are resolved by the shell before the result is passed to your program. If you really need to resolve wildcards in a C program you can use the function [glob()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob).